# Split a file based on

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, split

I
Hi everybody,

I need to split a file based on matched variable content in the file.
I need to split a file on a split parameter (here "///") only if the lines starting with :25: just before and just after the split parameter are different.
The files should then be named with the expression of the :25: tag.
I need to do this with a .cmd command...
I have tired with tokens, but have been unsuccessful.
Could somebody help me with this please?

For example, the below file initial file:

```
:01:BLABLA
:25:123456
:71:BLABLABLA1
:86:BLABLABLA2
:71:BLABLABLA3
:86:BLABLABLA4
///
:25:123456
:71:BLABLABLA5
:86:BLABLABLA6
:71:BLABLABLA7
:86:BLABLABLA8
///
:25:123457
:71:BLABLABLA0
:86:BLABLABLA9
```

should be split in two files:

**123456.TXT**

```
:01:BLABLA
:25:123456
:71:BLABLABLA1
:86:BLABLABLA2
:71:BLABLABLA3
:86:BLABLABLA4
///
:25:123456
:71:BLABLABLA5
:86:BLABLABLA6
:71:BLABLABLA7
:86:BLABLABLA8
```

**123457.TXT**

```
:25:123457
:71:BLABLABLA0
:86:BLABLABLA9
```

Comment: The lines with the :25: are always the first one _below_ the split parameter?

Comment: Hi Aacini. No, the :25: are not always the first below the split parameter. This is why the split should occur on the "///" and not on the ":25:".

Comment: You should insert a line between `///` and `:25:...` lines in your example _or_ carefully explain this point in the text!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set inFile=inputTextFile.txt
set outFile=tempFile.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%L in (%inFile%) do (
    set currentline=%%L
    if "%%L"=="///" (
        set outFile=tempFile.txt
    )
    if "!currentLine:~0,4!"==":25:" (
        set outFile=!currentLine:~4!.txt
        if exist tempFile.txt (
            if exist !outFile! (
                copy !outFile!+tempFile.txt !outFile!
                del tempFile.txt
            ) else ren tempFile.txt !outFile!
        )
    )
    echo %%L>>!outFile!
)
```

Just replace `inputTextFile.txt` with the correct file/path.

Comment: Hi MichaelS,
Thanks! But how could I make the script split the files on the "///" and not on the ":25:" ? Because the :25: is not always the first line below "///" and your script is cutting the file at :25:
Thanks !

Comment: @Chris My code doesn't split on :25: but on ///. If :25: was not found yet, it saves everything in a temp file. As soon as we've found :25: it renames the file to the string which follows :25:. On /// it starts writing into a new temp file again. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

del temp.tmp *.out 2> NUL

set "file=not25tag"
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if "%%a" equ "25" set "file=%%b"
   if "%%a" neq "///" (
      echo :%%a:%%b>> temp.tmp
   ) else (
      if not exist "!file!.out" (
         ren temp.tmp "!file!.out"
      ) else (
         echo ///>> "!file!.out"
         type temp.tmp >> "!file!.out"
         del temp.tmp
      )
      set "file=not25tag"
   )
)

if not exist "!file!.out" (
   ren temp.tmp "!file!.out"
) else (
   echo ///>> "!file!.out"
   type temp.tmp >> "!file!.out"
   del temp.tmp
)

ren *.out *.txt
```